# Is this the right way of making an array inside of an "else" statement on bash?

Tags: bash, shell-script

does anyone know if this is correct?
Is this the right way of making an array inside of an "else" statement on bash?
`else [[ $SELECTION != "a|b|c|x" ]]`

Comment: No, not correct. Always paste your script into `https://shellcheck.net`, a syntax checker, or install `shellcheck` locally. Make using `shellcheck` part of your development process.

Comment: Pretty much nothing in there is correct. Mainly, there's nothing there that has anything to do with arrays. Go back, think what it is you want to achieve, break it into small pieces, and work on them one at a time. For arrays, there's a number of questions here on the site that discuss them, and [BashGuide](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) also has a page on them: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Arrays

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that your intention was to test whether `$SELECTION` is *not* `a`, `b`, `c`, or `x`, and that you intended to do this for an "else-if" branch of your `if` statement.

Your test will test whether `$SELECTION` is not the literal string `a|b|c|x`.  The syntax is not correct if you intended to use the test in an "else-if" branch, which is written `elif [[ ... ]]`.

If you want to test if `$SELECTION` is something other than `a`, `b`, `c`, or `x`, then you may do that using

```bash
if ...; then
    ...
else
    case $SELECTION in
        a|b|c|x)
            # do nothing here
            ;;
        *)
            echo 'it is not a, b, c, or x'
    esac
fi
```

This uses a POSIX standard `case` statement which does nothing if the given value matches any of the `|`-delimited patterns, or calls `echo` if it doesn't match.

Or,

```bash
if ...; then
    ...
elif [[ $SELECTION != @(a|b|c|x) ]]; then
    echo 'it is not a, b, c, or x'
fi
```

This uses an extended globbing pattern which matches any one of the patterns separated by `|` within `@(...)`.

Or, getting rid of the awkward `!=` test:

```bash
if ...; then
    ...
elif [[ $SELECTION == !(a|b|c|x) ]]; then
    echo 'it is not a, b, c, or x'
fi
```

Note that the pattern has to be unquoted.  Whether the test is performed in an `elif` branch or not is irrelevant to the test itself.

See the "Pattern Matching" section of the `bash` manual.

Comment: re. the first sentence, yeah, the _syntax_ is correct if they want to run the `[[` "command" in the `else` branch, it's just that it doesn't _do_ anything by itself. Unless they meant something like `if ...; then ...; else [[ ... ]] && something here; fi`, but that's just ugly and they didn't show the `&&`, and I'd be wary of assuming they'd even know about that.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yes, it's more likely that the intended to use `elif`.